# django: request.LANGUAGE_CODE in JavaScriptCataLog do not return the page displayed one

Tags: javascript, django, catalog

As in my case, I want to translate strings within a js script. Basically I can made it work. I found that what the 'jsi18n' view returned depends on the preferred language of my chrome browser.
  If I set the preferred language to Chinese(Simplified), everything goes fine. But if I change the most preferred language to English, the 'jsi18n' view will return empty catalog array.

I figured out that the controlling variable or related one is 'request.LANGUAGE_CODE'. This is done by a test view:

```
def test_language(request):
    res = "";
    res += "translation.get_languages = %s<br>"%(translation.get_language(),)
    res += "request.LANGUAGE_CODE = %s<br>"%(request.LANGUAGE_CODE,)
    res += "get_language() = %s<br>"%(get_language(),)
    return HttpResponse(res);
```

The result of above code will be consistent with my browser settings.

So is there any way to control the request content(LANGUAGE_CODE or anything relevant) sent by browser?

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed.
The language in returned script is determined by get function in JavaScriptCatalog. I copied its code in django code base and pasted to a app 'languages/views.py' and did a minor change:

```
class JavaScriptCatalog(View):
...
def get(self, request *args, **kwargs):
    locale = request.GET('LANG')  #replace the original locale = get_language()
    ...
```

And all its depending items need to be copied either.
with project urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('languages/',include('languages.urls') ),
    ...
```

and languages/urls.py:

```
...
from . imporm views
...
urlpatterns = [
...                                      
    path('jsi18n/', views.JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(domain='djangojs',packages=['languages',]), name='javascript-catalog'),
...
```

In the template where we need to insert the following instead

```
{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}?LANG={{LANGUAGE_CODE}}"></script>
```

and don't forget to ensure this line in your settings:

```
Template = [ {
    ...
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
             ...
             'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
             ...
```